# How to split the column with delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `.csv` and I need to split the \n with ,

```
name,address
711-2880,Mankato\n96522\n(257) 563-7401
971-2880,CA\n965\n(01) 563-7401\nNebraska
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.address = df.address.str.split('\n')
```

My output:

```
    name        address
---------------------------------------------------
0   711-2880    [Mankato\n96522\n(257) 563-7401]
1   971-2880    [CA\n965\n(01) 563-7401\nNebraska]
```

Expected output:

```
    name        address
---------------------------------------------------
0   711-2880    [Mankato,96522,(257) 563-7401]
1   971-2880    [CA,965,(01) 563-7401,Nebraska]
```

I need to apply explode after separating by `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data in the `address` column is a list, not a string.  You first need to access the first element of this list (which is a string), and then do your split.

```
# Sample Data:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ['711-2880', '971-2880'], 
    "address": [['Mankato\n96522\n(257) 563-7401'], ['CA\n965\n(01) 563-7401\nNebraska']]}
)

>>> df['address'].apply(lambda col: col[0].split('\n'))
0      [Mankato, 96522, (257) 563-7401]
1    [CA, 965, (01) 563-7401, Nebraska]
Name: address, dtype: object
```

In the event that some of the address entries are empty, you can just work on the subset that have at least one list item (ignoring data if there are more than one item in the list).

```
mask = df['address'].apply(len).gt(0)
df.loc[mask, 'address'] = df.loc[mask, 'address'].apply(lambda col: col[0].split('\n'))
```

Comment: perfect, why my split(df.address = df.address.str.split('\n')
)  was not working, any enlighten on my method

Comment: If the column was a string, the split would have worked fine.  Rather, it is a list containing a string.  Note that `split` returns a list.  So we access the first item in the list (a string), split it, and then get a new list back.

Comment: in the original csv all columns are string where I am applying.

Comment: Try `df['address'].str.split(r'\\n')`

Comment: adding ir f i am using your code its working fine. but if I upload as csv to the notebook and executing. its same issue

Answer (score 0):

i copied and pasted your data into a .csv file and read it in the following way, then split the address using a lambda like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df

       name                           address
0  711-2880    Mankato\n96522\n(257) 563-7401
1  971-2880  CA\n965\n(01) 563-7401\nNebraska

df.address = df.address.apply(lambda x: x.split('\\n'))
df

       name                             address
0  711-2880    [Mankato, 96522, (257) 563-7401]
1  971-2880  [CA, 965, (01) 563-7401, Nebraska]
```

you could also do it your way but by making this change:

```
df.address.str.split(r'\\n')
```